# Using SQLite with Classic ASP

Tags: sqlite, asp-classic

I am building a "quick little" app which needs a small database.
I want to use Classic ASP (i.e. not ASP.NET), and I am wondering about SQLite for the database.

It is possible to use SQLite from Classic ASP?

How do I open / create / use a SQLite database from ASP?

Any help / pointers gratefully recieved!

Comment: Just curious, but when you say a small database and a quick little app, why not use the free version MySQL for this?  From my understanding, SQLite costs money per year to use, but has faster access and larger limitations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is easily possible.

1. First install the ODBC driver from http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/
2. Then you can connect with e.g. `DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=mydb.sqlite;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;`

I would suggest looking at [ajaxed library](http://www.ajaxed.org) which offers you a data abstraction for any database. Just configure the connection string and start working ...

Answer (score 0):

Driver;Database=mydb.sqlite;LongNames=0;Timeout=1000;NoTXN=0;SyncPragma=NORMAL;StepAPI=0;Version=3;