# How to use Android SQlite with classic asp file

Tags: android, sqlite, asp-classic

I have to develop an android application where I could link an Android SQlite with a classic asp file and using get and post methods of classic asp I need to fetch and post data from android SQlite database. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible as answered here:
[Using SQLite with Classic ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437533/using-sqlite-with-classic-asp)

It tells you where to get the sqlite ODBC driver and even provides a connection string.